# Does the header "If-None-Match" consume quota in youtube's api when the response code is 304?

Tags: express, http-status-code-404, response, status

That's the question, does the "If-None-Match" consume quota when the response code is 304 from youtube's api v3 or it's the same as when the response code is 200 which is 1 quota?

Didn't try anything, just a doubt

Answer (score 0):

All YouTube endpoints consume at least 1 point. There are no "free" requests available. This is for preserving their resources (think about a wrong loop, in a minute you can make 1M erroneus requests to the API)